# Second JSP page is not getting loaded after a AJAX POST request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have the below code in page1.jsp.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "page2.jsp",
            data: newdata,
            success:function(msg){
                return msg; 
            }                                                        
        })
```

Even after POST request, the page remains in page1.jsp and doesn't navigate to page2.jsp. I am seeing statusCode as "200 OK" when I did inspect element. How should I pass the control to page2.jsp if the AJAX call is success. If I am missing some code please correct me.

Comment: Using ajax, you have loaded the jsp in javascript. Now in place of `return msg` simply do something like following `$("the_element_you_inspected").html(msg);`

Comment: How would I navigate to page2.jsp instead of adding it to a html element in the same page? Eg :right now url is http://127.0.0.1:14588/page1.jsp. And I need to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:14588/page2.jsp on successful post.

Comment: If you want to change the page altogether, do not use ajax then.

Comment: this seems like a odd choice sending a ajax request to a page  and again navigating to the same page ...instead just send a  post request  to that page

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to the page you made the post to if the post success, you need to navigate in the success function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "page2.jsp",
    data: newdata,
    success:function(msg) {
        window.location = "page2.jsp";
    }
})
```